# Creating a Mac Version of iOS App, build error

Tags: ios, swift, macos, twilio, twilio-api

This is my first attempt to create MacOs version of my iOS app. I'm getting following build error, not sure how to fix this.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
ld: building for Mac Catalyst, but linking in dylib built for iOS Simulator, file '../Pods/TwilioVideo/Build/iOS/TwilioVideo.framework/TwilioVideo' for architecture x86_64
```

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Twilio Video` framework looks like it only supports being built for iOS and does not support the needed macOS architecture. This is also the case with the `Twilio Voice` framework that I've used.

We had to conditionally remove that dependency when building for macOS. When we used CocoaPods, we had a boolean at the top of our Podfile that indicated whether we were attempting to build for macOS and we had to manually toggle that when needed.

For example, do something like this in your Podfile:

```
compiling_for_ios = true # Change this when building for iOS/macOS

// Other stuff in your Podfile

if compiling_for_ios
   pod 'TwilioVideo'
end
```

Comment: Not sure if the code you have written above is actual code or a pseudo code? I'm getting error [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined local variable or method `compiling_for_ios' for #<Pod::Podfile:0x00007fb2e759b0e0>.

Comment: It should be actual code. I noticed the `if` statement is within a function in our file, but I wouldn't have expected that to prevent it from building. I'm not very familiar with Ruby.

Comment: `compiling_for_ios` and `$compiling_for_ios` are different variables in Ruby. Try adding or removing the `$`.

Comment: Awesome, I removed the $ from my answer as well